# What are some alternatives to the expression "take a page from"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, synonyms

The sentence is "For more in depth stress-management techniques...I like to **take a page** from cognitive behavioral theory."

Comment: I agree that an alternative is necessary because cognitive behavioral theory doesn't have any pages. Of course a book called 'Cognitive Behavioral Theory' could.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

For more in-depth stress-management techniques...I like to **refer to** cognitive behavioral theory.

or

For more in-depth stress-management techniques...I like to **utilize** cognitive behavioral theory."

or

For more in-depth stress-management techniques...I like to **borrow** [techniques] **from** cognitive behavioral theory.

Comment: I agree that you might consider something along the lines "borrow a concept from," "borrow a technique from, etc.  Note that if you are going to use the "borrow a page" or "borrow a leaf" idiom, you want to refer also to a (figurative) book, e.g., "I will borrow a page from my mother's book and use the fine china for Sunday dinner."

Answer (score 0):

Simply, "I turn to" or "look to" seem fine to me, but if you're trying to say the techniques are not copied, there's "draw inspiration from" or perhaps "expand upon."